# Very basic tuple implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, template, template-meta-programming, variadic

I've been messing with metaprogramming and variadic templates in C++, and I came up with this very primitive implementation of a tuple:

```
constexpr bool GreaterThanZero(int N)
{
    return N > 0;
}

template <int, typename...>
struct Helper;

template <int N, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Helper<N, Head, Tail...>
{
    typedef typename Helper<N-1, Tail...>::type type;
};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Helper<0, Head, Tail...>
{
    typedef Head& type;
};

template <int, typename...>
class TupleImpl;

template <>
class TupleImpl<-1>
{

};

template <typename Head>
class TupleImpl<0, Head>
{
protected:
    Head head;

public:
    template <int Depth>
    Head& get()
    {
        static_assert(Depth == 0, "Requested member deeper than Tuple");
        return head;
    }

    template <int Depth>
    const Head& get() const
    {
        static_assert(Depth == 0, "Requested member deeper than Tuple");
        return head;
    }
};

template <int N, typename Head, typename... Tail>
class TupleImpl<N, Head, Tail...>
{
protected:
    Head head;
    TupleImpl<N-1, Tail...> tail;



public:
    template <int M>
    typename std::enable_if<M == 0, Head&>::type get()
    {
        return head;
    }

    template <int M>
    typename std::enable_if<GreaterThanZero(M), typename Helper<M, Head, Tail...>::type>::type get()
    {
        return tail.get<M-1>();
    }

    template <int M>
    typename std::enable_if<M == 0, const Head&>::type get() const
    {
        return head;
    }

    template <int M>
    typename std::enable_if<GreaterThanZero(M), typename Helper<M, Head, Tail...>::type>::type get() const
    {
        return tail.get<M-1>();
    }
};

template <typename... Elements>
class Tuple : public TupleImpl<sizeof...(Elements)-1, Elements...>
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t size()
    {
        return sizeof...(Elements);
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int> test;
    Tuple<> test2;

    test.get<0>() = 1;
    test.get<1>() = 2;

    cout << test.size() << endl;
    cout << test.get<0>() << endl;
    cout << test.get<1>() << endl;
}
```

Being template metaprogramming, of course it looks terrible. Are there any ways I can clean it up? I've been picking up the nitty-gritty details of how templates work by messing around with stuff like this, but I'm sure I'm missing something that would simplify this.

Comment: Your implementation does not handle empty tuples :)

Comment: @Morwenn Ah good point :) what is acceptable behavior for that? Perhaps just an empty specialized class? I mean, there's nothing to get from it.

Comment: I actually tried to find a use case for it, but the only I could find was for some variadic metafunctions using tuples where there was a specialization for an empty parameter pack.

Comment: First obvious point: `GreaterThanZero` might as well just use: `return N > 0;` as its body.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Wow, I can't believe I did that. The code has been updated for both fixes.

Comment: This code compiles with gcc, but clang 3.5 gives "error: expected expression" error for the line `return tail.get<M-1>();`

Comment: @BuğraGedik have you tried with the latest Clang? It looks well-formed to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: @chbaker It needs to be tail.template get<M-1>(); See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is how I would clean this up, or maybe partially re-write [[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac1e7947152acd6a)]:

```
// helpers
template <typename T>
struct id { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using type_of = typename T::type;

template <size_t... N>
struct sizes : id <sizes <N...> > { };

// choose N-th element in list <T...>
template <size_t N, typename... T>
struct Choose;

template <size_t N, typename H, typename... T>
struct Choose <N, H, T...> : Choose <N-1, T...> { };

template <typename H, typename... T>
struct Choose <0, H, T...> : id <H> { };

template <size_t N, typename... T>
using choose = type_of <Choose <N, T...> >;

// given L>=0, generate sequence <0, ..., L-1>
template <size_t L, size_t I = 0, typename S = sizes <> >
struct Range;

template <size_t L, size_t I, size_t... N>
struct Range <L, I, sizes <N...> > : Range <L, I+1, sizes <N..., I> > { };

template <size_t L, size_t... N>
struct Range <L, L, sizes <N...> > : sizes <N...> { };

template <size_t L>
using range = type_of <Range <L> >;

// single tuple element
template <size_t N, typename T>
class TupleElem
{
    T elem;
public:
    T&       get()       { return elem; }
    const T& get() const { return elem; }
};

// tuple implementation
template <typename N, typename... T>
class TupleImpl;

template <size_t... N, typename... T>
class TupleImpl <sizes <N...>, T...> : TupleElem <N, T>...
{
    template <size_t M> using pick = choose <M, T...>;
    template <size_t M> using elem = TupleElem <M, pick <M> >;

public:
    template <size_t M>
    pick <M>& get() { return elem <M>::get(); }

    template <size_t M>
    const pick <M>& get() const { return elem <M>::get(); }
};

template <typename... T>
struct Tuple : TupleImpl <range <sizeof...(T)>, T...>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t size() { return sizeof...(T); }
};
```

Comments:

- With a bit more infrastructure (helper structs that are typically reused here and there) at the beginning, the main tuple implementation becomes just 20 lines.
- Instead of a recursive implementation, I have switched to multiple (variadic) inheritance of single tuple elements `TupleElem`, each with its own id `N` (so that each element is of unique type) and its own function `get()`. Hence `Tuple`'s function `get()` just redirects to the appropriate base class.
- Now a specialization of `TupleElem` for empty types can bring easily the desired [empty base optimization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization) without affecting the main tuple implementation.
- No specialization is needed for empty tuple. This definition includes empty tuple as a special case.
- No static assertions needed, an out-of-range index will give an error anyway (but you can add for better messages of course).

Now, there are so many things missing. I would start from support for rvalue references and, of course, constructors. If you want to get an idea, you can have a look at [my own tuple implementation](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/tree/master/include/ivl/root/core/tuple) (of which this one here is a miniature) including tuple views, expression templates for lazy evaluation, loops, algorithms, integration with all C++ operators, and much more.

Template metaprogramming does not have to look terrible!

Comment: Kudos for the non-recursive implementation :)

Comment: Agreed, that's cool. Not to mention, saves me from the unlikely case that the entire tuple won't be inlined with the recursive implementation.

Answer (score 10):

In C++14, it's possible to implement a tuple in a very concise way. However, you lose some functionality of `std::tuple` (`constexpr`ness and some perfect forwarding) because of some limitations of lambdas. The basic idea is to use a lambda capture as a fast compiler-generated struct. Here's a naive implementation just to give you the idea, but you should look at [Hana](http://github.com/ldionne/hana) to see the actual implementation:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>


template <typename ...Xs>
auto make_tuple(Xs&& ...xs) {
    // No perfect forwarding in the capture: maybe C++17?
    return [=](auto&& f) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(&xs...);
    };
}

template <std::size_t n, typename = std::make_index_sequence<n>>
struct get_impl;

template <std::size_t n, std::size_t ...ignore>
struct get_impl<n, std::index_sequence<ignore...>> {
    template <typename Nth>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(decltype(ignore, (void const*)0)..., Nth nth, ...) const
    { return nth; }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) get(Tuple& tuple) {
    return *tuple(get_impl<N>{});
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    auto xs = make_tuple('0', 1, 2.2);
    assert(get<0>(xs) == '0');
    assert(get<1>(xs) == 1);
    assert(get<2>(xs) == 2.2);

    get<2>(xs) = 2.2222222;
    assert(get<2>(xs) == 2.2222222);
}
```

[Here's the live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf7255384c2c297). Of course, it's not exactly clear how one would then have a `std::tuple<...>` type using this technique, but it can be done (see slide 33 of [this](http://ldionne.github.io/hana-cppcon-2014/)).

The largest advantages of this technique are:

1. Clarity. Once you get it, it's very simple and terse.
2. Opens new avenues for implementing many algorithms on tuples. For example, implementing `std::tuple_cat` is rather easy with this representation, while it's *very* hard with the usual `std::tuple` implementation.
3. Compile-time performance: I've done several benchmarks, and this implementation technique really improves on the usual `std::tuple` implementation in terms of compilation time.

Comment: Tried to implement it as a proof-of-concept: https://bitbucket.org/johannes_gerd_becker/pmt/src

Answer (score 5):

This currently probably won't compile:

```
const Tuple<int, int> t{};
t.get<1>();
```

Your recursive const version of `get` returns a non-const reference.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed too that a `const` was missing, but one couldn't see that easily among all the template, `enable_if` and `Helper` stuff.

Comment: Good point, that's pretty important.