# Dynamically call lambda based on stream input

Tags: c++, c++11, template, lambda

Some context: I have code that looks like this (minor issue noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22636151/14065)):

```
Statement  select("SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID > ? AND ID < ?");
select.execute(1462, 1477, [](int ID, std::string const& person, double item1, float item2){
     std::cout << "Got Row:" 
               << ID     << ", " 
               << person << ", " 
               << item1  << ", " 
               << item2  << "\n";
 });
```

Anyway this connects to the MySQL DB and starts pulling data from the server. So inside execute I loop over the results and call the lambda for each row:

```
    template<typename Action, typename ...Args>
    void execute(Args... param, Action action)
    {
        // STUFF TO SET up connection.
        // Start retrieving rows.


        while(row = results->getNextRow())
        {
            call(action, row);
        }
    }
```

So here row gets a single row from the socket connection with mysql (so it calls the lambda as it receives each row (no pulling the rows into memory first)). So the code I want to review is pulling the data and calling the lambda.

```
 // Statement::call

    template<typename Action>
    void call(Action action, std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>& row)
    {
        typedef CallerTraits<decltype(action)>   trait;
        typedef typename trait::AllArgs         AllArgs;
        Caller<trait::size, 0, AllArgs, Action>::call(action, row);
    }
```

This utilizes the helper class `CallerTraits` and `Caller` to pull the required rows from the stream and then call the lambda:

```
// CallerTraits
// Get information about the arguments in the lambda

template <typename T>
struct CallerTraits
    : public CallerTraits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template<typename C, typename ...Args>
struct CallerTraits<void (C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    static const int                        size = sizeof...(Args);
    typedef std::tuple<Args...>             AllArgs;
};
```

Then the `Caller`:

```
// Caller::call()
//    Reads the next argument required by the lambda from the stream.
//    An exception will be generated if the next argument on the stream
//    does not match the type expected by the lambda.
template<int size, int index, typename ArgumentTupple, typename Action, typename ...Args>
struct Caller
{
    static void call(Action action, std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>& row, Args... args)
    {
        // Get the next argument type required by the lambda.
        // As defined by index. Then remove all ref and const
        // bindings.
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<index, ArgumentTupple>::type    NextArgBase;
        typedef typename std::remove_reference<NextArgBase>::type           NextArgCont;
        typedef typename std::remove_const<NextArgCont>::type               NextArg;

        // Read the next value from the stream.
        NextArg val;
        row->getValue(val);

        // Recursively call Caller::call() (via doCall())
        // To get the next argument we need. All the arguments
        // are accumulated in the var args parameter `args`
        doCall<size-1, index+1, ArgumentTupple>(action, row, args..., val);
    }
};
```

Specialization when no more args need to be retrieved:

```
// Specialization of Caller::call() when we have got all the arguments.
// This simply calls the lambda with the arguments we have accumulated.
template<int index, typename ArgumentTupple, typename Action, typename ...Args>
struct Caller<0, index, ArgumentTupple, Action, Args...>
{
    static void call(Action action, std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>&, Args... args)
    {
        action(args...);
    }
};
```

Function to deduce parameter types:

```
// Function template needed because we
// can not deduce the Args... parameter manually in the call.
// so we let the compiler deduce it for us.
template<int size, int index, typename ArgumentTupple, typename Action, typename ...Args>
void doCall(Action action, std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>& row, Args... args)
{
    Caller<size, index, ArgumentTupple, Action, Args...>::call(action, row, args...);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I find your implementation a bit more complex than necessary. What you want to do is

1. fetch arguments from your "result set" `row` by calling its `getValue()` in a particular order;
2. use them (as arguments) to call `operator()` on function object `action`.

This can be done without recursion in **two lines**:

```
Do{row->getValue(std::get<N>(args))...};
action(std::get<N>(args)...);
```

where `args` is a tuple.

**Range**

---

Ok, now let's step back to see how this is possible. First, we learn how to count from `0` to a given number `L`, in order to construct range `0, ..., L-1`:

```
// holds any number of size_t parameters
template <size_t... N>
struct sizes { using type = sizes <N...>; };

// given L>=0, generate sequence <0, ..., L-1>
template <size_t L, size_t I = 0, typename S = sizes <> >
struct Range;

template <size_t L, size_t I, size_t... N>
struct Range <L, I, sizes <N...> > : Range <L, I+1, sizes <N..., I> > { };

template <size_t L, size_t... N>
struct Range <L, L, sizes <N...> > : sizes <N...> { };
```

This is a very common task, actually borrowed from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44832/39083). There's a better implementation with logarithmic (rather than linear) template depth, but I want to keep it simple here.

**"Do"?**

---

Next, an extremely helpful `struct` lets us evaluate expressions in a given order:

```
// using a list-initializer constructor, evaluate arguments in order of appearance
struct Do { template <typename... T> Do(T&&...) { } };
```

But beware, due to a [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) since at least version 4.7.0, GCC evaluates in the opposite order, [right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515948/2644390). A workaround is to provide a range in the opposite order, `L-1, ..., 0`, but I'm not doing this here.

**Caller**

---

Now, `Caller` has a generic definition with only two actual parameters, `ArgumentTuple` and `Action`. It also reads that tuple's size, say `L`, and constructs range `0, ..., L-1` in a third parameter:

```
// generic Caller
template<
    typename ArgumentTuple, typename Action,
    typename Indices = typename Range<std::tuple_size<ArgumentTuple>{}>::type
>
struct Caller;
```

Finally, a specialization deduces the generated range as variadic `size_t` parameters `N...`. A local tuple of type `ArgumentTuple` is used to store the arguments, and `std::get<N>` accesses its `N`-th element. That's it:

```
// Caller specialization, where indices N... have been deduced
template<typename ArgumentTuple, typename Action, size_t... N>
struct Caller<ArgumentTuple, Action, sizes<N...> >
{
    static void call(Action action, std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>& row)
    {
        ArgumentTuple args;
        Do{row->getValue(std::get<N>(args))...};
        action(std::get<N>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Please note that all the above code compiles but I have not seen it in action since I don't have the database infrastructure. I have just made a minimal definition

```
struct ResultSetRow { template<typename T> void getValue(T) { } };
```

So I can only hope it works for you.

I am sorry if this looks like a complete rewrite rather than a review, but I couldn't help it :-) At least I've kept the part of your code where you deduce `ArgumentTuple` from the lambda.

**PS-1** If your `ResultSetRow::getValue()` is `void`, then you need to adjust its variadic call to

```
Do{(row->getValue(std::get<N>(args)), 0)...};
```

so that each sub-expression evaluates to `int` rather than `void` (you cannot have a list-initializer made of `void` arguments).

**PS-2** I suspect you're not really managing resources here, so you don't need `std::unique_ptr`; a plain `ResultSetRow&` would suffice.

Comment: @iavr: Do you have any good references for using templates in the way you do. I am still having trouble reading the templates above (even after studying them, ie. I could probably not write that from scratch myself).

Comment: @LokiAstari Well, I'm a bit self-taught. The best resource I know on templates is the book by Vardevoorde and Josuttis, but even this has only one (limited) chapter on metaprogramming, and unfortunalety there's no edition covering C++11 (yet). Stroustrup's 4th edition of "the C++ programming language" does cover C++11 and again has one chapter on metaprogramming. Anyhow, these are good places to start. Specifically for `Do`, check [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates) and look for `struct pass`. There's some explanation there.

Comment: @LokiAstari For the "logarithmic depth" version of `Range`, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21943425/2644390) and look for `make_indexes`.

Answer (score 18):

I would have probably applied the following changes:

- Make `size` a `static constexpr` variable in `CallerTraits` instead of simply `static const`.
- Wherever a function simply passes variadic arguments whose types have been deduced, I would have passed `args` by [*universal reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582313/1364752) (now officially called [*forwarding reference*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf)) and used `std::forward` to forward the results to the following functions:

  ```
  template<int size, int index, typename ArgumentTupple, typename Action, typename ...Args>
  void doCall(Action action, std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>& row, Args&&... args)
  {
      Caller<size, index, ArgumentTupple, Action, Args...>::call(action, row, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  ```

  It's a bit hard and quite long to explain how it works exactly - you can find a great explanation in the answer linked above -, but the main point is that using this particular recipe implements perfect forwarding:

  ```
  template<typename X>
  void foo(X&& arg)
  {
      bar(std::forward<X>(arg));
  }
  ```

  The type of the parameters of `X&&...` in `foo` will have the same `const` and reference qualifications than the type of the corresponding parameters in `bar`. Anyway, the link is by far clearer than I am. Simply remember the recipe and that for this recipe to work, the type `X` ***has*** to be deduced by the function; it may not work if `X` is known from somewhere else.
- Instead of creating functions that take a `std::unique_ptr<ResultSetRow>&` parameters, I would have had `Caller<...>::call` and `doCall` them take a `ResultSetRow&` and dereferenced `row` right away. I don't know what is the exact return type of `results->getNextRow()` so I won't try to assume anything about it and the type that the main `call` should take as a parameter.

Comment: @LokiAstari For universal references: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers