# A generic "manual" loop unroller

Tags: c++, template

I want to force my compiler (C++ or perhaps CUDA) to unroll certain loops that it would rather not unroll. So, I've written the following:

```
template <size_t N> struct unroller {
    template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Function>
    static void unroll(const Function& f, ForwardIterator& it) {
        unroll<N/2, ForwardIterator, Function>(f, it);
        ++it;
        unroll<N-N/2, ForwardIterator, Function>(f, it);
    }
};
template <> struct unroller<0> {
    template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Function>
    static void unroll(const Function& f, ForwardIterator& it) { }
};

template <> struct unroller<1> {
    template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Function>
    static void unroll(const Function& f, ForwardIterator& it) { f(it); }
};
```

I can also manually write in the instances at sizes 2,3,4 or so to perhaps reduce the amount of work the compiler needs to do. However, I was thinking maybe I should be doing something involving template packs and index lists to really cut down on the amount of instantiation. What do you think?

Sample usage:

```
#include <iostream>

// unroller code here

int main()
{
    constexpr unsigned unroll_factor = 3;
    constexpr unsigned total_iterations = 12;

    static_assert(total_iterations % unroll_factor == 0, 
        "Unroll factor must divide the number of iterations");

    auto f = [](int n) { std::cout << n << ' ' << std::flush; };
    std::cout << "no manual unrolling: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < total_iterations; i++) { f(i); }
    std::cout << std::endl << "manual unrolling x " << unroll_factor << ": ";
    for(int i = 0; i < total_iterations; i++) {
        unroller<unroll_factor>::unroll(f, i);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't each `unroll` be a static member function?

Comment: If you want it to work on index lists, you will need to provide some utility to manipulate on type lists. Long time ago I made a [scrap version](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129058/type-list-with-utilities) of it. It would be great to see typelists being useful.

Comment: Also, Daniel [is right](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rDwJqHxGVP7rhHUq).

Comment: @DanielJour: Ah, yes, sorry, that was a mis-copy-paste.

Comment: @Incomputable: (!) Yes, Daniel is right. (2) Don't libraries such as brigand or Hana have these sorts of type lists? Also, why would I need a utility to manipulate type lists, seeing how the unroller only involves a small fixed number of types?

Comment: @einpoklum, it's for indices. I would want to iterate not only in usual linear fashion, but may be jumping around. Though if you're on GPUs or tight loops. it could have negative impact. About the libraries, if you think they are fit for the job, please use them. I'm a mere self-taught bachelor, so please take whatever I say with a grain of salt. I just thought that you might have some issues with licensing and tuning, so I linked my code.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are some errors that need to be fixed in order for your code to compile:

- `size_t` needs to be `std::size_t`, or alternatively there needs to be an `using std::size_t;` declaration.
- `no matching function for call`; you need to specify the template instantiation of the structure based on the "depth" as well as the function:

  ```
  // WRONG:
  unroll<N/2, ForwardIterator, Function>(f, it);
  // FIXED:
  unroller<N/2>::template unroll<ForwardIterator, Function>(f, it);
  ```

From a style perspective, I'd change the order of the template parameters to reflect the order in which the typenames appear in the parameter list (first the `Function`, then the `ForwardIterator`).

Then there's one thing that's a bit odd: Functions in the standard library which accept function objects (like `std::sort`, `std::transform`, ...) generally accept those function objects *by value*. This is done (probably) because that allows those functions objects to have mutable state. Your unroller accepts only references to *constant* function objects. That makes it (a bit) harder to have mutable state in the function object, like when you get one returned by some function:

```
auto make_that_function_object() {
    bool flag = true;
    return [flag](int n) mutable {
        if (flag) std::cout << n << ' ' << std::flush;
        flag = !flag; };
}
```

The lambda returned by above function cannot be used with your unroller. To fix it (as a user of your unroller), you need another (non-mutable) lambda which references the original one:

```
auto original = make_that_function_object();
auto wrapper = [&original](int n) { original(n); };
```

You could also solve this by accepting non-const references, though I'm not sure whether that's really better. (Accepting the function object by value does not solve the issue because then any changes to the internal state cannot be transferred "back up" the call chain or past "major" iterations of the top level loop.)