# Extract from typelist by runtime value

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variadic

I combined the ideas from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/127925/153110) and a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2157149/1557062) to create a new instance of a type extracted from a type list. The index of the desired type within the type list is provided at run time, only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class... Types>
class type_list {};

using list_t = type_list<A,B>;

template <class... Types>
static constexpr std::size_t length = sizeof...(Types);

template <std::size_t idx, class... Types>
class extract
{
    static_assert(idx < sizeof...(Types), "index out of bounds");

    template <std::size_t i, std::size_t n, class... Rest>
    struct extract_impl;

    template <std::size_t i, std::size_t n, class T, class... Rest>
    struct extract_impl<i, n, T, Rest...>
    {
        using type = typename extract_impl<i + 1, n, Rest...>::type;
    };

    template <std::size_t n, class T, class... Rest>
    struct extract_impl<n, n, T, Rest...>
    {
        using type = T;
    };

public:
    using type = typename extract_impl<0, idx, Types...>::type;
};

template <std::size_t idx, class TypeList>
struct type_list_extract;

template <std::size_t idx, template <class...> class TypeList, class... Types>
struct type_list_extract<idx, TypeList<Types...>>
{
    using type = typename extract<idx, Types...>::type;
};

template <std::size_t idx, class TypeList>
using type_list_extract_t = typename type_list_extract<idx, TypeList>::type;

template<std::size_t idx, bool done = false, class... Types>
struct action_wrapper
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> get_instance_by_id(std::size_t id)
    {
        if (id == idx)
        {
            using type = type_list_extract_t<idx, Types...>;
            return std::make_unique<type>();
        }

        static constexpr auto cont = length<Types...> < idx + 1;
        return action_wrapper<idx + 1, cont, Types...>::get_instance_by_id(id);
    }
};

template<std::size_t idx, class... Types>
struct action_wrapper<idx, true, Types...>
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> get_instance_by_id(std::size_t id)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

static std::unique_ptr<Base> get_instance_by_id(std::size_t id)
{
    return action_wrapper<0, false, list_t>::get_instance_by_id(id);
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr = get_instance_by_id(1);
    if (ptr)
    {
        ptr->foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prefer using `\n` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

---

Other than that, it looks like your code is rather clean and up-to-date style-wise.  I might suggest that the `get_instance_by_id` return the actual type, not the `Base` in case it gets used in a context where a specific one is known at compile time (or within other template code).

Comment: I don't think it is possible to return a more specific type. When `id == 0` the return type is `A` and if `id == 1` the return type is `B`. But `A` and `B` have nothing in common but their parent class `Base`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the common Base is *still there*.  You can provide more specific information in the return type for those that know about it, but code that expects a `Base*` will work just fine.  Lookup co-variant return types in virtual functions.

Comment: But there are no virtual functions involved? In my `get_instance_by_id` one path returns an `A` the other path returns a `B` so the method's overall return type must be the a common type of both. So it must be a `Base`. Am I wrong?

Comment: The individual concrete `get_instance_by_id` functions return `A*` or `B*` as they are implemented.  Code that calls generic `get_instance_by_id` can store the result in a `Base*`, as you have now.  But you have the additional feature that some other code that *does* know the exact type can use it, without downcasting.

Comment: But I don't see how this could work. Could you show me? What do I need to change?