# Bit packing and unpacking

Tags: c++, c++11, bitwise, variadic

I needed a variadic function to pack and unpack bits into integer types. This is my first attempt:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T pack(bool b)
{
    return b;
}

template<typename T, typename... Types>
constexpr T pack(bool b, Types... args)
{
    return (b << sizeof...(Types)) | pack<T>(args...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Types>
void unpack(T packed, bool& b1)
{
    b1 = packed & 1;
}

template<typename T, typename... Types>
void unpack(T packed, bool& b1, Types&... args)
{
    b1 = packed & (1 << sizeof...(Types));
    unpack(packed, args...);
}
```

Usage example:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << pack<int>(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0) << std::endl; // 150
    std::cout << pack<int>(1, 0, 1) << std::endl; // 5
    int val = pack<int>(1, 0, 1);
    bool b1, b2, b3;
    unpack(val, b1, b2, b3);
    std::cout << b1 << " " << b2 << " " << b3 << std::endl; // 1 0 1
}
```

Does this code contain any bugs, can it be improved, and are variadic templates used appropriately here (I still don't master their syntax)?

Comment: Two minor things I see: 1.) Replace each `std::endl` with `"\n"` 2.) In C++, `main()` doesn't need a `void` parameter.

Comment: OK, thanks. Anything about the core parts?

Comment: Nothing that I can see.  I'm not familiar with variadic templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Missing overflow check

One serious flaw that I see in this code is that the user needs to determine the number of parameters to `unpack`. This is a no go for a function whose output depends on a runtime input. Even worse there is no check that would tell the user that the actual number overflows the number of bits given to be unpacked into.

One possible solution would be to return an `std::vector<bool>` to fit the whole number.

The other solution would be to retain the current interface but to introduce error notification (by exception or return code).

### Unnecessary template parameter

Another thing regarding the `unpack` function:
It seems that you don't need the `Types` parameter in the recursion end, so it becomes:

```
template<typename T>
void unpack(T packed, bool& b1)
{
    b1 = packed & 1;
}
```

### Naming

The function parameter names could be better.
I assume `b1` is only appropriate in the top level call of the function. I cannot decide on a better name now, but it should indicate that it is the current bit. Likewise, `args` should be named `remainingBits` or something like this.

Comment: The unnecessary template parameter is a plain oversight. About the rest I will think about it - I will never use a  vector, this is exactly the point of this exercise, but if there is a way to make things more robust without a vector, I'll pursue it. About the naming, I have often seen "head" and "tail" but I don't find them quite appropriate.

Comment: If it is only for the sake of making it "static" then you could make the packed parameter a template parameter, thus removing the possibility of runtime values that forbid the use of the specific parameter list.

Comment: The `pack()` function needs to be evaluable also at compile-time (provided the passed arguments are), and actually it should be now - I hope the compiler is able to understand it - so that you can even use it in a switch case.
The `unpack()` function should accept whatever packed value at runtime. I will really think about this, but while I consider very valuable writing robust code, I think this is one of the cases in which the client should be really aware of what it's doing. The performance of this should be no worse than a handcrafted sequence of bitwise operations.

Comment: It is hard to be aware of the value of runtime variables if you don't check them. And if you check them beforehand you might forget to update the check together with the function call. Best way is to let the function itself do the checking and report an error if there is one. I find it a fairly harsh decision to put the burden onto the user of this function.

Comment: We have vector's `operator[]` that doesn't necessarily check the boundaries (and many implementations don't), and virtually any function in the C++ standard library is prone to undefined behavior. This thing should perform as fast as it can and I do not want to introduce any branching, not to mention dynamic memory allocation. (PS: I forgot... +1 for your excellent answer)

Comment: I place correctness over fastness. Also there are ways to introduce checks that are turned of for release builds (there are also "checked implementations" of `operator[]` that help to find bugs that would otherwise go unnoticed). If you are very keen about saving the user from dismal runtime (by avoiding a check that will most likely need only one clock cycle) provide a checked equivalent (like `at()`) or better a switch that will turn off the checking during release build.

Comment: If we have to bound check everything and performance is not critical, we may use Python which is elegant and powerful. However, making a checked implementation, with checks that can be disabled via compile switches, is really a cool idea.

Comment: The point is to default to the check being on. I would not even start about thinking to turn it off until I find hard evidence (by profiling) that it is a bottleneck.

Comment: OK, I see. Out of curiosity (this question may seem polemic but it's not in this context) do you use a "safe" STL, or do you enforce a "safe" mode in your STL? I really think gcc comes with a "do whatever you want, it's your responsibility" STL, and you have to pass a parameter to have some seatbelts.

Comment: I unfortunately do not use a safe implementation (I use the default one, which is why I make the point for the default to be "checks on") because I was to lazy to install a checked one yet. However, I am trying to use checked calls and write my own code with many checks. Using C++ indicates that you want to maximize performance but still you want to maximize correctness first. I myself am not clean of the fallacy of premature optimization :)

Comment: No problem, then, let the caller be aware or not of what it's doing. I think that the C++ way is not "no checks, we want our planes to crash" but just "do whatever you are sure about, no unnecessary check *on my side*". And I think you are right using a non checked STL, as your code is probably built in a way that there is no way you can read a vector beyond the boundary.

Comment: Actually, I think that I am wrong using a non checked stdlib. Even if I try to use the checked versions, something might slip through. There might be transitive errors in template functions from other libraries that can be caught this way... Sure the C/++ community has always had the "it is your own decision" mentality but I think it is dangerous to rely on the user making conscious decisions where in fact most decisions are made in unawareness. So the conscious decision should be to opt out from safety and not the other way around.

Comment: Well, I have tried to implement some compile-time checks. See my updated question :)

Comment: I think you overshot a little bit. Enforcing `sizeof(T)*8` gives you a minimum of 8 parameters that the user has to pass. Of course this is the only thing you could do to check at compiletime but as the problem lies in runtime I would do this check as an assert or with if and throwing an `std::overflow_error` exception. In any case the test should be against the real value and not the maximum. Besides that it looks good.

Comment: Actually the user can pass less than 8 parameters, he/she just cannot pass more than the ones the packed integer is able to provide, and this can be checked at compile time so why should I enforce it at runtime? I encourage you to try it - if there are no bugs in the code (which is a big if), I basically implemented the checks you asked for without a single runtime instruction.

Comment: I misread the relation sign (or better: I assumed it was right because I thought you did the test I was meaning). What I am going on about is not too many bits to extract into but too few (say you want to store the value 8 into 2 bits). This is a pure runtime problem (as the number could be 8 but it could also be always only two bits, who knows?) and can only be checked very conservatively during compile time. If the user happens to supply to few  bits she might accidentally (and without knowing) loose the most significant bits and there is no warning about this.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea of what you mean. Can you pastebin an example?

Comment: I have scribbled together a live example here: http://ideone.com/1R3xlP

Comment: @gd1: I just noticed that the default glibcxx already comes with checked implementations, you just have to turn them on by defining the macro `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. After doing this I found loads of iterator errors in one of my programs (which ran fine so far).

Comment: God, sorry to hear that.  Happy debugging. I'll do this check as well, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are aware of [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and you have your own reasons for doing this. Your `pack` seems fine, but `unpack` requires the user to set up a particular number of `bool` variables, which is not convenient. An alternative could be to use an `std::array` for the output:

```
template<size_t N>
using size = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

template<size_t N, typename T>
void unpack(size<N>, array<bool, N>& a, T) { }

template<size_t I, size_t N, typename T>
void unpack(size<I>, array<bool, N>& a, T packed)
{
    a[N-I-1] = (packed & (1 << I)) != 0;
    unpack(size<I+1>(), a, packed);
}

template<typename T>
std::array<bool, 8*sizeof(T)>
unpack(T packed)
{
    std::array<bool, 8*sizeof(T)> a = {};
    unpack(size<0>(), a, packed);
    return a;
}
```

which can be used like this

```
int val = pack<int>(1, 0, 1);
std::cout << unpack(val) << std::endl;
// prints 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

assuming a simple streaming operator

```
template<typename S, typename T, size_t N>
S& operator<<(S& s, const std::array<T, N>& a)
{
    for (auto i : a)
        s << i << " ";
    return s;
}
```

This way you know for sure there is no overflow in the output.

Now, `std::vector` is another alternative for output that may benefit from its compact `std::vector<bool>` specialization (and `std::bitset` of course). On the other hand, using `std::array`, one may obtain a really `constexpr` version of `unpack`, without recursion. `pack` may similarly be non-recursive, remaining `constexpr`. If you like this potential, I can elaborate.

---

**Update: `constexpr` version**

It turns out `pack` is quite tricky to make non-recursive *and* `constexpr`, but as promised, here is a non-recursive, `constexpr` version of `unpack` ([complete, live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29d2306b001eb49)):

```
template <size_t... N>
struct sizes { using type = sizes <N...>; };

template<size_t N, size_t... I, typename T>
constexpr std::array<bool, N>
unpack(sizes<I...>, T packed)
{
    return std::array<bool, N>{{(packed & (1 << (N-I-1))) != 0 ...}};
}

template<size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<bool, N>
unpack(T packed)
{
    return unpack<N>(typename Range<N>::type(), packed);
}

template<typename T, size_t N = 8*sizeof(T)>
constexpr std::array<bool, N>
unpack(T packed) { return unpack<N>(packed); }
```

where `Range<N>` contains sequence `0,...N-1` and is defined [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45334/39083). Now you can use it like this:

```
int val = pack<int>(1, 0, 1);

// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
std::cout << unpack(val) << std::endl;

// 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
std::cout << unpack<8>(val) << std::endl;
```

The first version returns the entire array needed to represent the precision of the given (integral) type. The second allows you to specify a shorter length for the array; the remaining (leftmost) bits are discarded.

Comment: Altough I am not the OP I would like to hear about the `constexpr` version of `unpack` :)

Comment: Well obviously yes.

Comment: Ok, I will be back as soon as possible... :-)

Comment: @gd1 Sorry, I forgot, it's just a shortcut. See edit for the definition.

Comment: @Nobody,gd1 Updated with `constexpr` `unpack`.

Comment: Nice, I did not know one could use the `...` to do this. Unfortunately I cannot give you another upvote.