# Dynamically call lambda based on stream input: Try 3

Tags: c++, template, template-meta-programming, c++14

Based on [Dynamically call lambda based on stream input: Try 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46397/507)

This fixes most of the points pointed out by [@Morwenn](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46448/507).

It has been generalized so anybody can call it.
The only extra part needed by the code is a function to retrieve values from a stream. This is passed as a template argument to  `callFunctor()` see the example below.

An example of how to use it:
Here I use `std::stringstream` as the input to be used for this example. In my own version I have a DB socket streaming rows from a MySQL DB and the lambda is called for each row. The point is the current version of `callFunctor()` can be used in any general environment (I hope somebody finds it useful).

#### main.cpp

```
#include "detail_caller.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct GetStreamValue
{
    // The input type to this method must match
    // the type of the first argument to `callFunctor`
    // As you will be passed the stream and asked to pull
    // a specific type from it.
    template<typename R>
    static R get(std::istream& stream)
    {
        R   result;
        stream >> result;
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::stringstream       data("10 13 Loki 4.5");

    callFunctor<GetStreamValue>(
        data,
        [](int val1, int val2, std::string const& val3, float val4)
        {
            std::cout << "Got(" << val1 << ", "
                                << val2 << ", "
                                << val3 << ", "
                                << val4 << ")\n";
        }
    );
}
```

#### detail_caller.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_DETAIL_CALLER_H
#define THORSANVIL_DETAIL_CALLER_H

#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct CallerTraits
    : public CallerTraits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template<typename C, typename ...Args>
struct CallerTraits<void (C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    static constexpr int                                        size = sizeof...(Args);
    typedef std::make_integer_sequence<int, size>               Sequence;
    typedef std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>                   AllArgs;
};

template<typename StreamValueGetter, typename Action, typename Stream, int... S>
void expandArgsAndCallFunctor(Stream& stream, Action action, std::integer_sequence<int, S...>)
{
    typedef CallerTraits<decltype(action)>  Trait;
    typedef typename Trait::AllArgs         ArgumentTuple;

    // ArgumentTuple  arguments(StreamValueGetter::template get<typename std::tuple_element<S, ArgumentTuple>::type>(stream)...);
    // action(std::get<S>(arguments)...);

    // The above two commented out lines
    // Represent the logic of the following line which retrieves
    // and calls the arguments in a single line thus avoiding temporaries.
    action(StreamValueGetter::template get<typename std::tuple_element<S, ArgumentTuple>::type>(stream)...);
}

template<typename StreamValueGetter, typename Action, typename Stream>
void callFunctor(Stream& stream, Action action)
{
    typedef CallerTraits<decltype(action)>  Trait;
    typedef typename Trait::Sequence        Sequence;

    expandArgsAndCallFunctor<StreamValueGetter>(stream, action, Sequence());
}

#endif
```

Comment: Which C++14-only features, if any, are you using?

Comment: Apparently `std::decay_t` and `std::integer_sequence`

Comment: `std::decay_t` is part of C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay

Comment: @Yuushi: c++11 => std::decay  c++14 => std::decay_t

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: @Yuushi: Its not as if I knew. Morwenn told me as part of the review for `Try2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to add more things to my answer on your previous post and noticed meanwhile that your already asked a following question (that's almost too fast! :o). I have done some additional reading about C++14 and integer sequences. And I have found some things in the standard that could help to improve your code again.

I realized at some point that you were using `int` as the `value_type` of `std::integer_sequence`. However, you initialize your `static constexpr int size` with the result of `sizeof...` and `sizeof...` returns a `std::size_t`, not an `int`.

Then I remembered that, along with `std::integer_sequence`, there is a `typedef` for `std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>` which is called `std::index_sequence` and which has been made to solve the kind of problem that your are trying to solve. Therefore, you should every occurrence of `int` by `std::size_t` and of `std::integer_sequence<int, N>` by `std::index_sequence<N>`.

---

Moreover, you don't need to create a `typedef` for `Sequence` in `CallerTraits`: you can deduce this class directly in `callFunctor` thanks to `CallerTraits<>::size`:

```
template<typename StreamValueGetter, typename Action, typename Stream>
void callFunctor(Stream& stream, Action action)
{
    using Sequence = std::make_index_sequence<CallerTraits<Action>::size>;
    expandArgsAndCallFunctor<StreamValueGetter>(stream, action, Sequence());
}
```

Note that I also replaced `decltype(action)` by `Action` since it is the same type.

---

Also, you can get rid of the `public` inheritance specifier for `CallerTraits` since you are using a `struct`. That does not change anything whatsoever.

---

Here is your code once refactored. I don't provide a link to an online compiler since none of the ones available has a good enough C++14 support (you just need to add some light library components though):

```
template <typename T>
struct CallerTraits
    : CallerTraits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template<typename C, typename ...Args>
struct CallerTraits<void (C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t                size = sizeof...(Args);
    typedef std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>   AllArgs;
};

template<typename StreamValueGetter, typename Action, typename Stream, std::size_t... S>
void expandArgsAndCallFunctor(Stream& stream, Action action, std::index_sequence<S...>)
{
    typedef CallerTraits<Action>        Trait;
    typedef typename Trait::AllArgs     ArgumentTuple;

    // ArgumentTuple  arguments(StreamValueGetter::template get<typename std::tuple_element<S, ArgumentTuple>::type>(stream)...);
    // action(std::get<S>(arguments)...);

    // The above two commented out lines
    // Represent the logic of the following line which retrieves
    // and calls the arguments in a single line thus avoiding temporaries.
    action(StreamValueGetter::template get<std::tuple_element_t<S, ArgumentTuple>>(stream)...);
}

template<typename StreamValueGetter, typename Action, typename Stream>
void callFunctor(Stream& stream, Action action)
{
    using Sequence = std::make_index_sequence<CallerTraits<Action>::size>;
    expandArgsAndCallFunctor<StreamValueGetter>(stream, action, Sequence());
}
```

Comment: The choice to use `int` over `std::size_t` was deliberate. I am trying not to use unsigned types for anything but bitfields.

Comment: @LokiAstari I understand your choice. Too bad that the standard only makes things easier for `unsigned` types :/