# n-dimensional Euclidean space calculation templates

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have been working with C++11 code that uses `std::vector[]` to store coordinates. Most often this code uses 2D or 3D but it occurred to me that it may be generally useful for n-dimensional Euclidean distance calculations.

Because these calculations are used within a simulation, they should be as fast as practical without sacrificing generality.

```
// euclid.h
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        throw std::domain_error("vector addition must have equal length vectors");
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(a.size());  
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 
                   std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<T>());
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator-(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        throw std::domain_error("vector subtraction must have equal length vectors");
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(a.size());
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 
                   std::back_inserter(result), std::minus<T>());
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
T squared_distance(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        throw std::domain_error("squared_distance requires equal length vectors");
    return std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), T(0), 
        std::plus<T>(), [](T x,T y){return (y-x)*(y-x);});

}
```

Here is some driver code to demonstrate usage.

```
// points.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "euclid.h"

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    out << "{ ";
    for (auto p : v)
        out << p << ' ';
    return out << "}";
}

#define say(x) std::cout << "" #x " = " << (x) << std::endl
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> origin{0, 0, 0}, a{3, 4, 5}, b{-1, -2, -3},g{0,0,0,0};
    say(origin);
    say(a);
    say(b);
    say(a+b);
    say(a-b);
    say(b-a);
    say(squared_distance(origin,a));
    say(squared_distance(origin,b));
}
```

The output from the program looks like this:

```
origin = { 0 0 0 }
a = { 3 4 5 }
b = { -1 -2 -3 }
a+b = { 2 2 2 }
a-b = { 4 6 8 }
b-a = { -4 -6 -8 }
squared_distance(origin,a) = 50
squared_distance(origin,b) = 14
```

I'm interested in general ideas for improvement or criticism of the existing code, but I also have some specific questions:

1. can the squared_distance calculation be made more efficient?
2. is there a nice way to reduce code duplication in the `+` and `-` operators?
3. I've tested with `int`, `float`, `double` and `std::complex`.  What else might be useful?
4. is there any point to accommodating `unsigned` types?
5. should I do anything about possible numeric overflow or underflow?
6. is there any point to having an `#ifndef` header guard in this file?

Comment: If you want performance, forcing a memory allocation for each coordinate sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reduce redundancy, I'd probably move the check for the inputs being the same size into a function template by itself, and just invoke that from the other three:

```
template <typename T>
void check_size(std::vector<T> const &a, std::vector<T> const &b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        throw std::domain_error("vector addition must have equal length vectors");
}
```

I'd then at least test with passing one of the input parameters by value, using it as the destination for the calculation, and returning it:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    check_size(a, b);
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), 
                   b.begin(), 
                   a.begin(), 
                   std::plus<T>());
    return a;
}
```

Although this doesn't always improve speed, it does often enough to be worth testing/profiling to see how well it works in this case.

Another possibility to consider would be using `std::valarray` instead. It's the forgotten step-child (so to speak) of the C++ standard, but it was designed specifically to support fast numeric calculations. It already defines equivalents of your `+` and `-` operators, as well as a `sum` and `*` operators, so your code comes out something like this:

```
std::valarray<double> origin{ 0, 0, 0 }, a{ 3, 4, 5 }, b{ -1, -2, -3 }, g{ 0, 0, 0, 0 };
say(origin);
say(a);
say(b);
say(a + b);
say(a - b);
say(b - a);
say(((a - origin) * (a - origin)).sum());
say(((b - origin) * (b - origin)).sum());
```

Since `std::valarray` defines all the operators we're using, the only other code we need is the `say` macro and the `operator<<` overload (minutely modified to take a `std::valarray` parameter instead of a `std::vector`).

Considering your more specific questions:

specific questions:

> - can the squared_distance calculation be made more efficient?

`std::valarray` and/or `std::array` might help--but for a relatively small number of dimensions, I wouldn't expect to see much difference.

> - is there a nice way to reduce code duplication in the + and - operators?

The code above attempts to answer this, to at least some degree.

> - I've tested with int, float, double and std::complex. What else might be useful?
> - is there any point to accommodating unsigned types?

I don't see a lot of point in unsigned types for this task. Yes, distances are always positive, but you can pretty easily end up with a negative number from an intermediate calculation, and you don't want that wrapping around to a large number as it would with an unsigned type.

> - should I do anything about possible numeric overflow or underflow?

Harder to say. It basically depends on the use to which you're putting the code. If you need the distance, there are ways of computing it that avoid the larger magnitude of the squared distance (even as an intermediate), and are fairly fast to compute as well--but they're still slower than computing the squared distance, in which case the final result is also often the single largest value you deal with, so there's not a lot you can about overflow.

In floating point, subtraction is one of the prime culprits that can/will lead to precision loss. At least in theory, you might prefer to avoid it if possible, but for finding a squared distance I don't know of a lot of alternatives either.

> - is there any point to having an #ifndef header guard in this file?

The compiler will (or should, anyway) give errors if you include it twice in the same translation unit, so it wouldn't hurt. Of course, you're unlikely to include it twice in the same translation unit directly, but its getting included via two other headers wouldn't be all that rare an occurrence.

I was going to mention `std::array` as well, but while I was writing this, I see @Morwenn has written one about that already.

Comment: Sorry about that :/

Comment: I had completely forgotten about `std::valarray` and just now read the relevant bits of the standard about it. Seems tailor-made for what I'm trying to do, so I'll do some performance tests with `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::valarray` and post results soon.

Comment: I think `std::valarray` was forgotten by its designers first, then by the users. When you start using it you realize you want more, but this more is simply not there :-(

Answer (score 6):

Regarding duplication, you could have a single function for applying a function elementwize:

```
template< typename T, typename U, typename BinaryFunc >
auto elementwise_apply(const vector<T> &x, const vector<U> &y, BinaryFunc func)
     -> vector<decltype(func(x[0], y[0]))>
{
    // apply `func` to all arguments and return a vector
}
```

and then declare your other binary operations in terms of it

```
template< typename T>
vector<T> operator+(const vector<T> &x, const vector<T> &y)
{
    return elementwise_apply(x, y, plus<T>());
}
```

and so forth.

I also agree with seeing if you can use `array` rather than `vector` -- the more that you can make happen at compile-time rather than run time, the better. Similarly, fewer dynamic allocations and fewer non-inlined functions would generally lead to more efficient code.

I would also suggest that you consider making a `point` struct that has an `array` member (or a `vector` member), rather than using a naked `array`, so that all of your functions will only applicable to objects meant to actually refer to points.

Answer (score 6):

I am working on this topic so I have much to say, please bear with me. I am starting with your question (2), which is the most interesting. At the same time, I am making a series of abstraction and generalization steps. The final result will appear weird at first, but is quite more powerful than your current setup, in different ways. I will then discuss your remaining questions quite shortly. All my suggestions can be seen in a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7888e81f27dfffbc).

### Generalizations

Before coming to your question, let's look at a couple of limitations in the current approach

```
operator+(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
```

(A) Why should the vectors have the same value type? Better, why have the same kind of containers in the first place?

(B) Why limit the operation to two arguments? there are unary operators out there, and there are n-ary functions as well.

Issue (A) can be dealt with by a few type functions:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
struct subs_type;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename... A, typename S>
struct subs_type<C<T, A...>, S> { using type = C<S, A...>; };

template <typename... A>
using container_common_type = std::common_type<typename A::value_type...>;

template <typename A, typename... B>
using container_result =
    subs_type<A, typename container_common_type<A, B...>::type>;
```

In words, we are finding the common type of all value types of the given container types, and we are generating a new container of the same kind (e.f. `std::vector` with the first container and the common value type. Additional template parameters like allocators etc. are reused.

Issue (B) can be dealt with by a quite generic function object `apply`:

```
template <typename F>
struct apply : F
{
    using F::operator();

    template <typename A, typename... B>
    typename container_result<A, B...>::type
    operator()(const A& a, const B&... b) const
    {
        using R = typename container_result<A, B...>::type;

        if (_or()(a.size() != b.size()...))
            throw std::domain_error("vector operation must have equal length vectors");

        R result;
        result.reserve(a.size());
        auto r = std::back_inserter(result);
        transform(*this, r, a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin()...);
        return result;
    }
};
```

In words, `apply` applies function object of type `F` to input arguments of types `A, B...`. There are a few interesting generalizations here:

- It requires *at least* one input argument `A`, but otherwise the fully variadic definition allows unary, binary, or arbitrary n-ary functions.
- It *derives* function object `F`, *overloads* its `operator()`, and uses *itself* as a function when entering `transform`. This allows *recursive* application so that the same object can apply to scalars as well as any kind of container. We'll see an example below under your question 3.

However, it keeps the same logic of storing the result, using `reserve` and `back_inserter`. I am discussing alternatives later on.

The underlying operations required by `apply` are the following:

```
struct _or
{
    constexpr bool operator()() const { return false; }

    template <typename A, typename... B>
    constexpr bool operator()(A&& a, B&&... b) const
        { return std::forward<A>(a) || operator()(std::forward<B>(b)...); }
};

struct _do { template <typename... A> _do(A&&...) { } };

template <typename F, typename R, typename I, typename E, typename... J>
void transform(const F& f, R r, I i, E e, J... j)
{
    for (; i != e; _do{++r, ++i, ++j...})
        *r = f(*i, *j...);
}
```

Function object `_or` is pretty much self-explanatory: it's an n-ary generalization of `operator||`.

Function `transform` is maybe the weirdest of all. It is more or less an n-ary generalization of `std::transform`. `r` is the output iterator, `i,e` are the current iterator and `end` respectively of the first container, and `j...` are the iterators of the remaining iterators. The function object and the output iterator come first, to allow for variadic input iterators in the sequel. All iterators are passed by value.

In words, `transform` has an output and a number of input iterators. All iterators advance *in parallel*. At each iteration, function object `f` is applied to the dereferenced values of all input iterators `*i, *j...` and the result is stored to the value of the output iterator `*r`.

Auxiliary struct `_do` allows for variadic, sequenced evaluation of its contained sub-expressions. I use it quite frequently, see `Do` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45334/39083) for more.

### Code duplication

> (2) is there a nice way to reduce code duplication in the + and - operators?

Ok, whatever tools the language provides for generic programming, there comes a time when macros become inevitable. **Macros?** Before rushing to criticize, look at the following and please keep your mind open:

```
MYLIB_OP_UNARY(plus,  +)
MYLIB_OP_UNARY(minus, -)

MYLIB_OP_BINARY(add, +)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(sub, -)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(mul, *)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(div, /)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(mod, %)

MYLIB_OP_BINARY(eq,  ==)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(neq, !=)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(gt,  >)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(lt,  <)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(ge,  >=)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(le,  <=)

MYLIB_OP_UNARY(_not, !)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(_and, &&)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(_or,  ||)

MYLIB_OP_UNARY(bit_not, ~)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(bit_and, &)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(bit_or,  |)
MYLIB_OP_BINARY(bit_xor, ^)
```

These macros are defined and then only used once to generate the code for the required operators. You are then free to undefine them to avoid pollution. Be careful to use a prefix in the name of the macros to avoid collisions. I have assumed here you are making a library called `mylib`.

Macros are needed because each expands to around 20 lines of code (which is the minimal possible, despite abstractions), and I wouldn't like to copy this code 20 times or more. And if you think that `operator==` is an overkill, someone else will not.

Now here is how `MYLIB_OP_BINARY` is defined (`MYLIB_OP_UNARY` is similar):

```
#define MYLIB_OP_BINARY(NAME, OP)                               \
                                                                \
namespace operators {                                           \
struct NAME                                                     \
{                                                               \
    template <typename A, typename B>                            \
    constexpr auto                                               \
    operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const                               \
    -> decltype(std::forward<A>(a) OP std::forward<B>(b))        \
        { return std::forward<A>(a) OP std::forward<B>(b); }      \
};                                                              \
}                                                               \
                                                                \
template <typename A, typename B>                               \
typename container_result<A, B>::type                           \
operator OP(const A& a, const B& b)                             \
{                                                               \
    return apply<operators::NAME>()(a, b);                       \
}                                                               \
```

First, inside a separate namespace `operators` we are capturing the meaning of each C++ operator into a function object. This is similar to `std::plus` etc. but

- applies to any C++ operator
- is non-template, allowing easier use

Then, for each operator, we define the corresponding "vectorized" operator for containers *and* scalars by just calling `apply`.

Note that this latter definition, although taking arbitrary types of input arguments, does not interfere with other potential overloads, because the result type

```
typename container_result<A, B>::type
```

is only valid if `A,B` are instances of class templates defining their own `value_type` (so, usually containers). Otherwise, other overloads are considered only. So we don't need `enable_if` in this; `container_result` is enough for substitution failure.

I hope you can now see that this macro is not possible to simplify further by existing language abstraction mechanisms. It would only be convenient to eliminate it if we could make it an one-liner, but then we'd loose all the nice generalizations exposed above.

In my work, I separately capture *all* C++ operators [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/type/fun/op.hpp) and then define the "vectorized" counterparts [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/fun/op/op.hpp).

### Namespaces

Regardless of any other precautions, we are defining a number of very generic operators that extend the language in a way that may not be desirable in combination with (or compatible to) other code or other libraries. As an extra measure of precaution, define everything in a separate namespace. Check the live example for details. Again I have assumed you are building a library called `mylib`.

### Efficiency (accumulation)

> (1) can the `squared_distance` calculation be made more efficient?

I don't want to elaborate too much here. A simple change would be fine:

```
return std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), T(0),
    std::plus<T>(), [](T x,T y){T z = y-x; return z*z;});
```

We just introduce a temporary to avoid doing the subtraction twice. But I would suggest to measure because most probably the optimizer is doing this anyway for us.

### Efficiency (element-wise operations)

I have left the issue of storing the result inside `apply`. Using `std::vector::reserve()` along with `std::back_inserter` means that

- We are limited to containers having `reserve()`, hence most probably to `std::vector`.
- We resize the container at each iteration. Even if we are not reallocating, we need to at least update the vector size.

There are numerous options here, but in most cases one would have go to a lower level of implementation, or use another kind of container.

For instance, if we could [build a vector to allow uninitialized storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585675/building-a-vector-to-allow-uninitialized-storage), we could give the appropriate size without initializing elements. `transform` would then only *initialize* each element instead of *copying* a new value. This *can* be implemented with a specialized allocator to be used with `std::vector`.

But then, why should `apply` decide what is the returned container type and how it should be initialized, resized, or copied? To me, the ultimate solution is to [delay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evalution) evaluation of the result by using [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates). Then, expression `a - b` only returns a temporary object holding references to `a, b` and knowing the function type (like std::minus), while `c = a - b` does the actual work, initializing according to `c`'s type.

As I said, I am working on this topic. [Here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/view/apply.hpp) is the *sequence view* (object behaving like a container) corresponding to `apply` as given above, and [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/iter/apply.hpp) is its iterator. I am afraid this code will be probably unreadable because it's using much more entities defined elsewhere, and because it has taken many more steps of abstraction and generalization than shown here.
Libraries like [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html), [boost::ublas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) or [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) are similar in this respect (actually, in using expression templates *and* in being unreadable internally)!

I am sorry I am not giving any more concrete solution here, but I feel this is a huge topic, and if you start in this direction, you may soon realize you should be using an existing library in the first place.

Anyhow, the good news are that you now have a single generic implementation of all operations so whenever you decide to invest on a more efficient implementation, you'll only have to define it once.

### Other types

> (3) I've tested with int, float, double and std::complex. What else might be useful?
>
> (4) is there any point to accommodating unsigned types?

You won't need anything for unsigned types. The definitions given here will work fine and conversions will be made according to language rules by `std::common_type`, even for `std::complex`.

Other types? **Anything!** For instance, why not other containers? Consider:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> >
    u{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 4, 5}},
    v{{-1, -2, -3}, {5, 6, 7}};
say(u);
say(v);
say(-u);
say(+v);
say(u+v);
say(u-v);
say(v-u);
```

This works automatically now, for any level of nested containers, thanks to recursion. It wouldn't work with your code.

One "glitch" is that separation between vectors and scalars is done by checking for member type `::value_type` as I said above. Unfortunately this is not quite appropriate because e.g. `std::complex` has this type but is not a container. I have a simple workaround in my live example by also requiring `::size_type`, but all such issues will be resolved by [C++ concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29).

One comes soon to realize that adding a scalar to a vector would also be convenient. This results in four combinations of operations. Then how about an n-ary function? This would result in `2^n` combinations. I have a generic solution and [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/test/array/vec_op.cpp) is a test sample of my code showing just a few of the things than can be done. But this goes way too far.

Another issue is that we have mostly ignored *move semantics* here. If we were to write this code in the most generic way, we should use rvalue references and forwarding everywhere. This is not so hard to do, but I have skipped it and used `const&` parameters almost everywhere.

### Type promotion

> (5) should I do anything about possible numeric overflow or underflow?

For element-wise operations, nothing.

For accumulation operations like `squared_distance`, maybe yes. For instance, adding up `1000` values of type `int` might only fit into a `long`, and `1000` values of type `float` might only fit into a `double`. It would be convenient to have type promotions automatically done somewhere, but to decide exactly when a promotion is needed requires run time information, otherwise we may be promoting "just in case", which is contrary to the C++ principle

> *don't pay for what you don't use*

I believe the user should be aware of such issues. Lazy evaluation may come to the rescue again: in an expression `c = f(a, b)`, if `f(a, b)` is just a temporary intermediate object, then the actual work is only done when the type of `c` is known. This is exactly why `std::accumulate` and `std::inner_product` take another argument for the output. I also have a generic solution here, but again this goes too far.

For now, I would suggest to just use the right types for the input vectors (e.g. `double`) when an operation is expected to overflow the result. This is maybe too much a burden to the user, but we don't live in a perfect world.

### UPDATE: Corrections

I now realize that using `common_type` is not the right approach for finding the return type. It works for operators like `+,*` but not e.g. for boolean operators where the result is always `bool`. Moreover, `common_type` won't work with nested containers with different value types; it's simply not defined for such cases.

It's not too hard to make the return type depend on the *operation* `F` as well, using `decltype` as in the "capturing" function objects, or `std::result_of`. However, a further complication when considering nested containers with different value types is that substitution of the value type is not enough. For instance, `std::vector<T>` is actually

```
std::vector<T, std::allocator<T> >
```

so one has to substitute `T` for a new type, say `S`, in *both* the container and the allocator, to yield

```
std::vector<S, std::allocator<S> >
```

Assuming that containers follow this structure (in particular, they all have allocators), I have updated the previous code accordingly, but I am only giving here a link to a new [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8622f02529699fb) to avoid making this answer even longer. For something more general without too much boilerplate, the containers should provide for such type substitution *themselves*; but to my knowledge, unfortunately this is not the case in STL.

We can now apply binary operators between containers of as diverse value types as

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > u{{-2, 0, 0}, {3, 4, 5}};
std::vector<std::vector<int> >    v{{-1, 0, -3}, {5, 6, 5}};
```

as shown in the live example, along with some interesting cases like `u < v`.

Ok, that's it, I hope I will write no more!

Answer (score 4):

I know that this won't answer any of your questions, but instead of using `std::vector<T>`, you should consider using `std::array<T, N>` to represent your data. Here is why this design could be more interesting:

- `std::array<T, N>` uses stack memory while `std::vector<T>` uses heap memory. I bet that a stack-allocated array will be a little bit more efficient than a heap-allocated vector.
- Mathematically speaking, it does not make any sense to change the size of a vector. Therefore, a fixed size container will also ensure that the size does not change.
- You won't have to bother with `reserve` anymore.
- In your functions, you make sure that the vector you add or subtract have the same size. If you use `std::array<T, N>` to store your data, you will get an implicit compile time check instead of an explicit runtime one:

  ```
  template <typename T, size_t N>
  std::array<T, N> operator+(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b)
  {
      std::array<T, N> result;
      for (size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
      {
          result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```

  Moreover, since your loop has a static condition, it may be unrolled at compile time by the compiler.

Comment: Just a note: efficiency-wise (regardless of changing the container type), you are dropping the need to update the container size at each iteration, but at the same time you are implictly default-initializing all elements *before* entering the loop. This is exactly why Edward is using `reserve` and `back_inserter`, to avoid unnecessary initialization. Otherwise, one could say `std::vector<T> result(N);` and then write the same `for` loop as yours. Without measurements I cannot say which approach is better, but for me none is good enough (see discussion in my answer).

Comment: Plus, I bet you can't fit 10^7 elements on the stack, so it really depends on the application. The fact that STL algorithms are defined on iterators rather than containers has something to say (not on convenience, but at least on performance and genericity).

Comment: @iavr Those were some of my concerns, but since he mainly talked about 2D and 3D vectors, I considered that those weren't major drawbacks. I don't believe that many people perform computations in 10^7 dimensions Euclidean space.

Comment: @Morwenn You're right. Since modern physics says that all of spacetime can be described in [11 dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory), more than that seems extravagant.

Comment: @Morwenn,Edward Well, algorithms for 2D/3D or even 11D spaces would rather use `std:array` if the number of dimensions is (compile-time) fixed. On the other hand, a color 1024x768 image has roughly 2,5M elements and I routinely do vector operations on such objects, or [even worse](http://image.ntua.gr/iva/files/agm.pdf). Element-wise operations, norms and squared distances remain the same in both cases.

Comment: @iavr Since the original purpose was Euclidean space vectors, I wouldn't have used the class for other purposes. I would probably have made another class for another kind of vector. The problem is that the word "vector" is polysemous.

Comment: @Morwenn Well, what makes a space Euclidean are certain mathematical properties that have nothing to do with the number of dimensions. It's not a matter of polysemy, rather a matter of application domain.

Answer (score 3):

## Results

Based on the feedback received, (thank you all for taking the time!) I wrote three different versions using `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::valarray`. I then modified my test code to create a vector of one million randomly created 3D points (using `double`) and then called the `squared_distance` template function to populate a second results array with the squared distance between a fixed random point and each of the million other points.  I then used the `time` command under Linux to record the User time taken for each of the three variants.  Ten trials were done for each and the summary of the timing is shown below.

```
          valarray  array   vector
average     0.976   0.904   1.730
variance    0.000   0.002   0.020
```

As is clear from the results, both `std::valarray` and `std::array` are almost two times faster than my original `std::vector` version with `std::array` being fastest.  That version of the code is shown below:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T squared_distance(const std::array<T,N>& a, const std::array<T,N>& b)
{
    T accum(0);
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        T delta = b[i]-a[i];
        accum += delta*delta;
    }
    return accum;
}
```